# IOS: unknown crash on variable setter

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, setter

I have a piece of code that is updating height constraint value.
The code is running perfectly on my device but I have received tons of crash report from Crashlytics.
I cannot reproduce the crash.

Here is the crash report, it seems the setter of a variable is having problem.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000100205974

0  newapp                         0x102899974 ProductDetailViewController.detailViewHeightConstant.setter + 83 (ProductDetailViewController.swift:83)
1  newapp                         0x102841f24 ViewConstraint.prodDetailViewRelayout(productDetailView:viewController:) + 50 (ViewConstraint.swift:50)
2  newapp                         0x102739714 ProductDetailView.reloadProdDetailViewLayout() + 4338997012 (<compiler-generated>:4338997012)
3  newapp                         0x1028a010c ProductDetailViewController.updatePV(isHidden:pv:) + 4340465932 (<compiler-generated>:4340465932)
4  newapp                         0x10289c0c4 ProductDetailViewController.handleProductDetailResponse(response:) + 891 (ProductDetailViewController.swift:891)
5  newapp                         0x10289ac9c ProductDetailViewController.apiCallback<A>(with:) + 4340444316 (<compiler-generated>:4340444316)
6  newapp                         0x102830800 partial apply for closure #3 in MyUIViewController.loadApi<A>(_:_:param:method:showActInd:errorView:mapArray:) + 215 (MyUIViewController.swift:215)
7  RxSwift                        0x104200b48 $s7RxSwift14ObservableTypePAAE9subscribe6onNext0F5Error0F9Completed0F8DisposedAA10Disposable_py1EQzcSg_ys0H0_pcSgyycSgAOtFyAA5EventOyAKGcfU0_ + 388
8  RxSwift                        0x104200d50 $s7RxSwift14ObservableTypePAAE9subscribe6onNext0F5Error0F9Completed0F8DisposedAA10Disposable_py1EQzcSg_ys0H0_pcSgyycSgAOtFyAA5EventOyAKGcfU0_TA + 40
9  RxSwift                        0x1041b6778 $s7RxSwift17AnonymousObserverC6onCoreyyAA5EventOyxGF + 40
10 RxSwift                        0x1042032b8 $s7RxSwift12ObserverBaseC2onyyAA5EventOyxGF + 180
11 RxSwift                        0x1042034f0 $s7RxSwift12ObserverBaseCyxGAA0C4TypeA2aEP2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGFTW + 20
12 RxSwift                        0x1042026a4 $s7RxSwift32ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink33_277A93ABA8477198C125F3F26B2D4B62LLC9scheduler8observer6cancelADyxGAA0efG9SchedulerC_xAA10Cancelable_ptcfcAA10Disposable_pAH4sink_AA5EventOy1EQzG5eventt_tcfU_ + 312
13 RxSwift                        0x1042030d4 $s7RxSwift32ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink33_277A93ABA8477198C125F3F26B2D4B62LLCyxGAA5EventOy1EQzGAA10Disposable_pIeggnr_AE_AJtAaK_pIegnr_AA12ObserverTypeRzlTRTA + 160
14 RxSwift                        0x1041f6160 $s7RxSwift13MainSchedulerC16scheduleInternal_6actionAA10Disposable_px_AaF_pxctlF + 404
15 RxSwift                        0x1042029d0 $s7RxSwift32ObserveOnSerialDispatchQueueSink33_277A93ABA8477198C125F3F26B2D4B62LLC6onCoreyyAA5EventOy1EQzGF + 432
16 RxSwift                        0x1042032b8 $s7RxSwift12ObserverBaseC2onyyAA5EventOyxGF + 180
17 RxSwift                        0x1042034f0 $s7RxSwift12ObserverBaseCyxGAA0C4TypeA2aEP2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGFTW + 20
18 RxSwift                        0x104223bf4 $s7RxSwift4SinkC9forwardOnyyAA5EventOy1EQzGF + 48
19 RxSwift                        0x10422703c $s7RxSwift15SubscribeOnSink33_B44C3DD7F62EF81799E6347E59A266A2LLC2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGF + 32
20 RxSwift                        0x1042276e4 $s7RxSwift15SubscribeOnSink33_B44C3DD7F62EF81799E6347E59A266A2LLCyxq_GAA12ObserverTypeA2aFP2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGFTW + 20
21 RxSwift                        0x104223bf4 $s7RxSwift4SinkC9forwardOnyyAA5EventOy1EQzGF + 48
22 RxSwift                        0x1041df1f0 $s7RxSwift23AnonymousObservableSink33_95EBF5692819D58425EC2DD0512D115ALLC2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGF + 232
23 RxSwift                        0x1041df414 $s7RxSwift23AnonymousObservableSink33_95EBF5692819D58425EC2DD0512D115ALLCyxGAA12ObserverTypeA2aFP2onyyAA5EventOy1EQzGFTW + 20
24 RxSwift                        0x104203900 $sTA + 76
25 RxSwift                        0x1041b6874 $s7RxSwift11AnyObserverV2onyyAA5EventOyxGF + 44
26 RxSwift                        0x104203694 $s7RxSwift12ObserverTypePAAE6onNextyy1EQzF + 188
27 newapp                         0x1027909a0 closure #2 in closure #1 in ApiClient.request(url:method:param:header:encoding:) + 139 (ApiModel.swift:139)
28 Alamofire                      0x1031978f4 $s9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0Vy10Foundation0B0VG_Tg5Tm + 188
29 Alamofire                      0x10319b954 $s9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0Vy10Foundation0B0VG_Tg5TATm + 44
30 Alamofire                      0x103176fe4 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 28
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b6cc29a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b6cc3524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b6ca66fc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 860
34 CoreFoundation                 0x1b6f7b748 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
35 CoreFoundation                 0x1b6f7661c __CFRunLoopRun + 1724
36 CoreFoundation                 0x1b6f75c34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
37 GraphicsServices               0x1c10bf38c GSEventRunModal + 160
38 UIKitCore                      0x1bb0a822c UIApplicationMain + 1932
39 newapp                         0x1027bd410 main + 22 (AppDelegate.swift:22)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b6dfd800 start + 4
```

Here are parts of code that may be related to the crash.

```
class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var detailViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var detailViewHeightConstant : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
        // line 83
            detailViewHeight.constant = detailViewHeightConstant
        }
    }
}



class ViewConstraint {

    public func prodDetailViewRelayout(productDetailView: ProductDetailView, viewController :ProductDetailViewController){
        ...

        var detailViewHeight: CGFloat
        detailViewHeight = 123

        productDetailView.setFrameHeight(height: detailViewHeight)
        // line 50
        viewController.detailViewHeightConstant = detailViewHeightConstant

        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: can only see you trace,do you have crash error like "out of index"?

Comment: @CharlieCai there has no other obvious error log

Comment: not quite sure,but could you try detailViewHeight.constant = newValue on line 83

Comment: @CharlieCai "newValue" is for set not didSet, so it does not work

Comment: you are right.weird ,seems very straightforward code.what could possibly go  wrong

Comment: @CharlieCai I just have a thought, may be detailViewHeight is nil as it is weak variable. I need to add more logs in app in order to see if my guess is correct or not.